# Make key lowercase in List of Dictionaries (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Been looking through Stackoverflow and documentations for 2 days now, I am a beginner, and I just can't progress. I am using **Python 3.8**.

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
books = [{'Type': 'Book', 'Date': '2011', 'Publication Year': '2011', 'Place Published': 'New York', 'Publisher': 'Simon & Schuster', 'Author': 'Walter Isaacson', 'ISBN': '978-1-4516-4853-9', 'Title': 'Test Steve Jobs'}, {'Type': 'Book', 'Date': '2001', 'Publication Year': '2001', 'Place Published': 'Oxford', 'Publisher': 'Oxford University press', 'Author': 'Peter Hall', 'ISBN': '978-0-19-924775-2', 'Title': 'Test Varieties of capitalism: the institutional foundations of comparative advantage'}]
print(books)
```

I want to make the key "Type" into a lowercase "type".
But with the following List Comprehension it somehow makes the key to a value and vice versa.

```
lower_list = [ { v:k.lower() for k,v in d.items() } for d in books ]
print(lower_list)
```

I end up with `[{'Book': 'type',....` when it should be `[{'type': 'Book',....`

I am struggling with understanding the list comprehension syntax still, so would be grateful for 1. somebody explaining what my list comprehension does in plain English and 2. how to change it to achieve what I am looking for. :)

Thank you!

Comment: `lower_list = [ { k.lower():v for k,v in d.items() } for d in books ]` ? You are inverting key and values

Comment: I knew somebody would answer within seconds with the easiest fix! THANK you so much! Can you explain to me what the ":" does here?

Comment: this is the separator beetween the key and the value in the dict you can see this comprehension like that : 
`[{ myKey:myValue for myKey,myValue in d.items() } for d in books]`
 in *myKey,myValue in d.items()* you're unpacking a tuple generated from a dict like this one : (key, value) , dunno if it's clearer now :p

Comment: THAT makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to explain. :)

Comment: A follow-up question: I am now trying to do the lowercasing for every key, BUT the ISBN. But apparently it's not valid syntax:  ` ` `[{v:k.lower() for k,v if k not "ISBN" in d.items()} for d in books] ` ` `

Comment: I sum everything up and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

So your first problem:

```
lower_list = [ { k.lower():v for k,v in d.items() } for d in books ] ?
```

You was inverting key and values.

Your last question how to skip lowercasing the ISBN key:

```
[ { k if k is "ISBN" else k.lower():v.lower() for k,v in d.items()} for d in books ]
```

But you should consider using a for loop: if your need more operations or conditions, it would start to be difficult to modify further.

```
my_final_books = []

for d in books:
    for k,v in d.items():
        if k is "ISBN":
            key = k
        else:
            key = k.lower()
        # or ternary form key = k if k is "ISBN" else k.lower()
        my_final_books.append({key:v})
        # do more logic here
```

Comment: Wow. You are amazing! Thank you so much. In the meantime, I was able to produce this. Took me a whole day. But your version seems more elegant. ` <code> def lower_but_ISBN(lower_dict):
    newdict = {}
    for k, v in lower_dict.items():
        if not k == 'ISBN':
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                v = lower_dict(v)
            newdict[k.lower()] = v
        else:
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                v = lower_dict(v)
            newdict[k] = v        
    return newdict
                
for item in books:
    print(lower_but_ISBN(item)) </code>`